# Skim does not pop up after building .tex file with LaTeXTools in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text

How do I make Skim pop up after a build for a LaTeX-document in Sublime Text 2, while using LaTeXTools? Currently, Skim opens or refreshes the window but stays in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a configurable option in LaTeXTools called `keep_focus` that controls this.

- To permanently stop it, you can set `keep_focus` to `false` in your `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` file (which you can find in the menu: `Preferences -> Package Settings -> LaTeXTools -> Settings - User`).
- To temporarily switch to having Skim move to the foreground, use the keyboard toggle, which is three key strokes (`cmd + l`, `t`, `f`).